# How can I overwrite taxonomy field link output?

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms

I am using Drupal 7 and the Views module. I made a very simple page showing nodes with the Views module, where I want to show only one field, which contains taxonomy terms.

I want to rewrite standard link from this page to my own variant. I selected "Rewrite results" and wrote my link. In the view, those links are not changed: they are going to taxonomy term pages.

I know that if I used a view showing taxonomy terms (not nodes), I could checkout the field for standard taxonomy output, but in a node view there is no such possibility.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that like follows.

Go to your view and click on filed (having taxonomy) to change the settings.

1. Change the **Formatter** option to *plain text*. (If you choose Formatter as 'Link' that won't work even you write Rewrite Results')
2. Check *output this filed as link* and enter your path. Or you can also use'Rewrite the output  of this filed'

[image]

That's it.

Answer (score 0):

1. Find the machine name for your vocabulary. (`Hint`: go to
   admin/structure/taxonomy and click "edit" next to the vocabulary.
   The vocabulary's machine name will appear in the URL).
2. Copy **page.tpl.php** into your theme folder and rename it
   **page--vocabulary--[machine name].tpl.php**. Of course replace
   "[machine name]" with the actual machine name.
3. If **page.tpl.php** doesn't already exist in your theme folder, grab a
   copy from your base theme, if you are using one, or the
   modules/system folder. (If you are customizing more than one
   vocabulary, just repeat this step for each.)
4. Open **template.php** in your theme folder (create it if it doesn't
   exist) and paste in the function below. Replace "THEME" with the
   name of your theme.

By adding the below code, you are "suggesting" a new template be used that deals specifically with the vocabulary being loaded.

```
function THEME_preprocess_page(&$vars) {
  if (arg(0) == 'taxonomy' && arg(1) == 'term' && is_numeric(arg(2))) {
    $term = taxonomy_term_load(arg(2));
    $vars['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'page__vocabulary__' . $term->vocabulary_machine_name;
  }
}
```

5. Clear all caches.